# Multiple Joins with Filters in DAX

Tags: t-sql, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to recreate simple SQL query in DAX. The output Query needs to work in Power BI Report Builder and I have been trying all day reading all sorts of PowerBI / DAX online resources to rewrite this.

A little bit about the data:

- The data is structured in three tables, CustomCar, Engine and Chassis.
- Basically "CarId" is the key that connects all three tables.
- Let's assume all tables have more than 20 columns. so only a few of the columns are needed in the final output.
- All three tables (CustomCar, Chassis and Engine) have an `IsActive` property (the relationship between Engine/Chassis to CustomCar is MANY-TO-ONE. Because an engine might blow up and they change it therefore somehow we want to track which Engine is on the car today and what engine was on it last year, however, at any time, there is only one active engine for each car.. The same goes for Chassis)
- Both Engine and Chassis have 'Manufacturer' and 'Model' columns so in the output query they need to be identified from each other.
- I am not trying to sum any sort of sales number, just a list of cars with their current configuration.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Select
    CC.Name, CC.Model as 'CustomCarModel', CC.MaxSpeed,
    Ch.Manufacturer as 'ChassisManufacturer', Ch.Model as 'ChassisModel', Ch.ManufacturedDate as 'ChassisManfDate',
    E.Manufactuer as 'EngineManufacturer', E.Model as 'EngineModel', E.Power, E.CylCount, E.ManufacturedDate
From CustomCars CC
Join Chassis Ch on Ch.CarID = CC.CarId
Join Engine E on E.CarID = CC.CarID
where
CC.IsActive = 1 and CC.FirstTestDriveYear < 1980 and
Ch.IsActive = 1 and
E.IsActive = 1
```

More info, here are my tables.

Classic Car:

```
CarId (Primary Key) | Model | MaxSpeed | NumOfPax | TankCapacity | IsActive | FirstTestDriveYear  |....
1            | SuperChev    | 220      | 2        | 60           | 1        | 1985                |
2            | CustomBranco | 185      | 2        | 90           | 1        | 1979                |
3            | RebuiltToyo  | 251      | 4        | 20           | 0        | 1990                |
```

Chassis:

```
ChassisId (Primary Key) | CarId (Foreign Key)| IsActive | Manufacturer | Model | ManufacturedDate  | ...
1                       | 1                  | 0        | ACME Chassis | M1    | '04-Jan-1985'     | ...
2                       | 1                  | 1        | SuperChassis | T5    | '03-Feb-1987'     | ...
3                       | 2                  | 0        | Ford         | S2    | '25-Mar-1965'     | ...
4                       | 2                  | 0        | Ford         | S2    | '25-Mar-1968'     | ...
5                       | 3                  | 0        | JapanChass   | X123  | '25-Feb-1988'     | ...
6                       | 2                  | 1        | Ford         | S8    | '08-Jul-1978'     | ...    
7                       | 2                  | 0        | Ford         | S2    | '25-Mar-1968'     | ...
8                       | 3                  | 1        | JapanChass   | Y765  | '25-Feb-1992'     | ...
```

Engine:

```
EngineId (Primary Key)  | CarId (Foreign Key)| IsActive | Manufacturer | Model | ManufacturedDate  | Power  | CylCount   | ...
1                       | 1                  | 0        | GM           | AB1   | '04-Jan-1985'     | 320    |    8       | ...
2                       | 1                  | 1        | Bently       | ZY2   | '03-Feb-1987'     | 285    |    8       | ...
3                       | 2                  | 0        | Ford         | S2    | '25-Mar-1965'     | 290    |    6       | ...
4                       | 2                  | 0        | Ford         | S2    | '25-Mar-1968'     | 292    |    6       | ...
5                       | 3                  | 0        | Toyota       | X123  | '25-Feb-1988'     | 180    |    4       | ...
6                       | 2                  | 1        | Ford         | S8    | '08-Jul-1978'     | 222    |    8       | ...
7                       | 2                  | 0        | Ford         | S2    | '25-Mar-1968'     | 320    |    8       | ...
8                       | 3                  | 1        | Toyota       | Y765  | '25-Feb-1992'     | 211    |    6       | ...
```

Comment: How does you table relations look?  This is the first thing you need to take case of. 3rd icon in left pane. When you have this done, you can build your visuals and filter the whole page or only the single visual on IsActive.

Comment: @Aldert I added some sampe data but I do not need the ui tool to build the query, I need to write that query from scratch as this is the first peice of a very complicated sql query which unfortunately ReprotBuilder's query builder chokes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work around for this. I added the query when adding the data pipeline in Power BI dashboard and will use the values from the query as is.